# Is system() call in C program safe?

Tags: c, linux

I wanted to use linux commands in my C program. I know, we can use system() call to execute commands by spawning it. 
Whether system() call is safe or not? When I disassemble the exe of my C program, I can see the commands which I use in my program :(

[Edit]    below is the example for my program and image has a "echo hello" command in it.

```
arul@OA2:~/work/images/samples$ cat a.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("hai\n");
    system("echo hello\n");
    return 0;
}
arul@OA2:~/work/images/samples$ gcc a.c -o a
arul@OA2:~/work/images/samples$ ./a
hai
hello
```

[image: Look at the below image which contains my commands <code>system()</code> call]

Comment: If your intent is to obfuscate, the answer is no. The process list will show the command you are executing, whether you use `system()` or the `exec*()` family. If what you want to run is available as a library, use the library instead. For example, if you want to get a user entry from the user database, don't use `system("getent passwd user")`, use `getpwnam()` and family instead.

Comment: Safe from what?

Comment: How do you think this (its arguments being viewable in the binary program) makes `system()` more unsafe?

Comment: Btw, you should probably test out command `strace` and environment variable `LD_PRELOAD`, before spending any time at all obfuscating your strings in your source code.

Comment: No `system` is not safe. Beware of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection). Read [advanced linux programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and use `fork`, `execve`, `waitpid` etc...

Comment: You could also use `strings` on your binary to find out strings inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System() is vulnerable as the command used can be replaced. To avoid it we can use library functions like `fork execl, execv, execle, execve, execlp, execvp`.

Answer (score 5):

[www.securecoding.cert.org](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/2130132) reference say:

> Use of the system() function can result in
>   exploitable vulnerabilities, in the worst case allowing execution of
>   arbitrary system commands. Situations in which calls to system()have
>   high risk include the following:
>
> - When passing an unsanitized or improperly sanitized command string
>     originating from a tainted source
> - If a command is specified without a path name and the command
>     processor path name resolution mechanism is accessible to an attacker
> - If a relative path to an executable is specified and control over the
>     current working directory is accessible to an attacker
> - If the specified executable program can be spoofed by an attacker

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by safe. Will it magically put a virus on your computer? No. Does it mean you have to take special precautions to prevent malicious behavior? Yes. Is it generally a good idea? Not really. Will it obfuscate the commands you use so you can't see them when the exe is disassembled? No.

Comment: I mean to say there are options available for _**code injection**_ for the command used, If the executable is shared to the user.

Comment: Then the second point is important. The executable can be replaced, and thus you are executing a potentially unknown executable.

Comment: Yes  you got the point @ duncan. That's why system is vulnerable, example simply if you replace a command from `echo hello` to `mv /bin /somename` from the above example. system is non-operational.

Answer (score 0):

In some situations it's probably not dangerous, but i think best practice would be to use a library or function that does what you need, such as `execve()`.

(ADDENDUM)

If you mean safe, as in will not reveal strings in the data, then that's not how you want to do it.
But if your application needs to be secure in that way, you really should be using proper functions, `system()` seems to be a last resort to just get things done fast and dirty.